# How to use objects of arraylist in Jfreechart

Tags: object, arraylist, jfreechart

I am writing a programme to visualize some data which are stored in a few arraylists. 
I'm using Jfree Line char but the problem is I have to make an arraylist in the chart class and set an array list from use interface to the one in chart class using setter. like

```
LineChartDemo linechartdemo1 = new LineChartDemo("All Sensors");
            linechartdemo1.setList(list.getsList());
            linechartdemo1.setTimelist(list.getTime());
            linechartdemo1.create();
            linechartdemo1.pack();
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(linechartdemo1);
            linechartdemo1.setVisible(true);
```

So my question is that how can I make an instance of my arraylist class and use it in chart class(The normal way objects work) I tried making a new object and use getters like

```
Datalist list = new DataList();
list.getMaxvalue();
```

But it's not working and this is how I'm using my list in other classes. This time it doesn't work in my chart class and it requires me to make an arraylist in chart class and set an arralist from user interface class. 
Can Somebody please help?
How can I make and instance of my ArrayList class like above and use it in chart class and why is it not working in JfreeChart?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear where you're having problems; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117743).